# SqlException was unhandled: Login failed for user 'sa' :

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, sqlexception

I'm trying to connect to sql server 2008 express remotely in visual studio 2010, but I'm getting an exception: 
`SqlException was unhandled: Login failed for user 'sa'`, despite of entering correct username and password.

The following is an example of `app.cofig` file in windows form, which is trying to connect to sql server express:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
 </configSections>
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="Prod" connectionString="Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source= 192.100.100.199\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = inventory;User Id=sa;Password = Pass;MultipleActiveResultSets = True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Could anyone please tell me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you login to that database from your machine using Enterprise Manager?

Comment: I can login successfully remotely to Sql express using sql management studio

Comment: What is the authentication mode used, are they different, does setting it to mixed makes any difference (coz for windows i think sa would be disabled)

Comment: I *really* hope you're just checking with `sa` to confirm connectivity, and aren't planning to use that account permanently in your application.

Comment: It was already in Mixed mode authentication. I connected to sql express remotely in Mangement studio using the same username and password as specified in above connection string

Comment: Do you get any error state or code ? anything to add onto `login failed for user sa` ?

Answer (score 6):

"Mixed authentication" is not enabled by default when installing SQL Server. Check this in SQL Server Management Studio Express - right click server node, open properties, go to Security, enable "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode".

Answer (score 0):

Create a login for user 'sa' using Sql management studio. If the login is already created then check for server roles as public and sysadmin rights is checked.

Comment: I *suspect* that "despite of entering correct username and password" means we can assume that an account does at least exist

Comment: @Marc Gravell, oh yes you're right later on checked the comments. may be the server roles are different.

Comment: Server role was already by default checked as "sysadmin" and "public"

Answer (score 0):

As dkl has mentioned previously, you need to make sure that mixed authentication mode is installed on your Sql server service.

When you choose mixed authentication mode during the installation of sql server, the setup prompts you to enter a password. This is the password that SS uses for the sa logon.

If mixed mode is enabled and you still cant get through then someone has the changed the password on you.